# Controller Override Magento (existing methods not overridden)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to override an Ajax controller in Magento community module. The problem is that my controller gets called only if the method doesn't exist. I can't override any of the overridden controller methods.

Here is my code

config.xml:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <overriden_module>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <My_Module before="Overriden_Module">My_Module</My_Module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </overriden_module>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

I am overriding an ajax controller so - AjaxController.php :

```
<?php
require_once (Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Overriden_Module') . DS .'AjaxController.php');

class My_Module_AjaxController extends Overriden_Module_AjaxController {

//This is an overridden method and no hit
public function streetAction() {
    die('FOO');
}

// This action is not overridden and gets called
public function otherAction(){
    die('BAR')
}

}
```

As requested this is the router part from the module I'm overriding:

```
<routers>
        <module_name>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Module_name</module>
                <frontName>frontname</frontName>
            </args>
        </module_name>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Module_Name before="Mage_Checkout">Module_Name_Checkout</Module_Name>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you listed Overriden_Module as a dependency in your module configuration, to ensure it get's loaded before yours? I'd have thought you'd run into other problems if not, but you never know.

Comment: @Cags Yes it is listed as a dependency. I am overwriting models and blocks as well. I also checked the merged config.xml and the loading order is just as it should be. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: `<depends />` has nothing to do with this. What does the other module's standard router configuration look like?

Comment: @benmarks Thanks for your reply. I updated the question with the module router config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some debugging i found out what was causing the issue.
The module i'm rewriting was also defining admin router with the same name as the frontend one. When Magento searches for a router match to dispatch it will first check the admin routers and therefore running the admin controller of the module and not even checking the front routers.

If you dump `$this->_routers` in the code bellow you will see what i'm talking about.

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php line 174:`

```
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
        foreach ($this->_routers as $router) {
            if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the answer is to simply override the admin controller